# How to copy and paste catalog objects between catalogs in obiee12c

Tags: obiee

We have created some analytical reports using obiee12c analytics in our test server. Now, we need to transfer these reports to our production server. How we can copy these reports from the test server and paste into the production server.

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/bi/biee/r1013/merge/merge.html

Comment: I believe another post has the same question.
Please, look here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71123688/11929229