# How to deploy dashboard from the test server to the production server

Tags: oracle, business-intelligence, obiee

We have created a dashboard using obiee12c in the test server. After performing UAT from test server, we need to deploy this tested dashboard to the production. What could be the easiest way to deploy dashboard from test server to the production server.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1. Archive and Unarchive each dashboard object or the entire folder containing those objects. Look at this documentation
   https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12211/biee/BIESG/GUID-E163C218-3E30-4FD8-91BE-DE909B90CC63.htm#BIESG3594
2. Look into Source Control and Automated deployment as beautifully presented on this article from Robin Moffat https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2016/12/source-control-and-automated-code-deployment-options-for-obiee/

Recommendation: Use the first one until you implement the second one.